# ng-model is not passing through correct value

Tags: angularjs

I have a select element in which users can select a orderBy filter,

```
%select{
  "ng-change"  => "select()", 
  "ng-model"   => "selectedItem", 
  "ng-options" => "option.sortBy for option in listOfOptions"}
```

This is the `listOfOptions`

```
$scope.listOfOptions = [
  {sortBy: 'Release date',  value:'release_date'},
  {sortBy: 'Newly added',   value:'created_at'}
];
```

And the `select` function,

```
$scope.select = function(){
  console.log($scope.selectedItem.value)
}
```

In the view the select box shows both the release date and newly added options, but when I select one of them I get the error,

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

So it looks like $scope.selectedItem is undefined, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: if i'm not mistaken selectedItem should present in the this not in the $scope object. *this.selectedItem* should work for you

Comment: you should change ng-options to below `"ng-options" => "option in listOfOptions"}`

Comment: @The changing from scope to this fixed it.

Comment: @alucardu you welcome

Comment: @The a quick follow up, maybe you can point me in the right direction. What if I want to inverse the result of `created_at`. Because now the last record that's been created gets put at the end of the list. While I want it to be the  first. But I don't want to change how `release_date` is displayed.

Comment: @alucardu have you tried to sort by date?

Comment: @The I was more thinking about where to place the code that inverses the order. Should I make a if/else statement in my JS, `if this.selecteditem.value == created_at{ inverse order} else { //}`

Comment: @The like so, http://plnkr.co/edit/HCncjLYyPD0EiyHFDOs9?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Well I did a plunker and the select works as expected

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZnTRY36YWqU7MK4RHEBq)

app.js:

```
  $scope.listOfOptions = [{
    sortBy: 'Release date',
    value: 'release_date'
  }, {
    sortBy: 'Newly added',
    value: 'created_at'
  }];

  $scope.select = function() {
    console.log($scope.selectedItem.value)
  }
```

Index.html:

```
<select ng-change="select()" ng-options="option.sortBy for option in listOfOptions" ng-model="selectedItem"></select>
<p>{{selectedItem}}</p>
```

Can you provide your angular version ?